# What's the name of font used in this trailer (David Brin's EXISTENCE)?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

What's the name of font used in this trailer:
David Brin's EXISTENCE : Official Teaser: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANVT0hYbAfE
(the font that appears in the center throughout the first 30 seconds of the trailer)

[image]

Comment: Try isolating the characters and making a query in http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: I've tried that, doesn't return the right result (only similar fonts).

Comment: WhatTheFont is a good option. You can also try http://www.identifont.com/.

Comment: more of this font can be found in this other video http://vimeo.com/41734476 and there is an official website if you google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sansation, available from FontSquirell.com

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Sansation

Answer (score 1):

The font is called Sansation you can download for free from http://www.fontsaddict.com/font/sansation-light.html